# How to make a Countup timer and store it in the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer

I would ask you about how to make a Countup timer in JS and PHP.

I need it to count up in Seconds, Minutes and Hours. I also want to make it remember the time when im gone from the page, and when i enter it again. And I want to store it in the database. I want a toggle button that can start it and stop it. And besides that I want a reset button that can reset the timer.

I am using jQuery.

Comment: what you tried..?

Comment: at least write some of your code in order to let us help you, nobody's gonna write code for you for free here

Answer (score 0):

You should try yourself first and than when you got stucked you should answer.
Yet I'm giving an example of counter.
JavaScript

```
function count(){
x = 1;
x = x+1;
document.getElementById('counter').value=x;
setTimeout(count(), 1000);
}
```